# HDD Sata to USB-3 with enclosure recognized but not working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, external-hard-drive, sata-to-usb

I recently bought a 1To HDD from WD with an enclosure giving me a cable to connect the HDD's Sata port to a USB3 port on windows 10 computers (2 computers have been tested, the same result as follow). The HDD is recognized in device manager as 
"Disk drives"
"JMicron SCSI Disk Device"
But I can't access the HDD.

The thing is that I also have a chromebook, and everything works fine with this HDD enclosure. No problem at all!

Do you have any idea ? I thought about drivers but everything is up to date normally.

Thank you,
bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you to check if the WD HDD is recognized in [Disk Management in Windows](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=gEPAub) then, @Herosix! Since this is a brand new drive, you won't be able to access it in the Window File Explorer *(This PC/My Computer)*, unless you [**Initialize the drive**](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=1Hrhj4) first, and then [**partition & format it**](http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=KcK0qF)  through the Disk Management. After these two procedures have been completed and you have assigned a drive letter to the hard drive, you should be able to access its capacity and use it however you like.

Just a reminder, always make sure you backup your data to multiple storage locations. This is the surest way to avoid any potential data loss in the future.

Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, this is exactly what it was needed thanks again! :)